# Make-up Air intake tripping smoke alarm

Tags: vent, smoke-detectors

I have the MUA intake vent on the patio of my condo, located on the ground floor, so the patio has a ceiling.  Frequently when I barbecue, smoke rises and moves to MUA intake, and gets into the mechanical room in enough concentration to trip a smoke alarm.  The MUA pump does not itself have a damper, so I'm interested in finding a damper that I can install over the outdoor vent, that I can manually close whenever I operate the grill.  Any suggestions for such a unit?

The vent is located just below the patio ceiling, just out of arm's reach, so I would want to have some kind of lever or screw to open and close it from below.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Is it a duct smoke detector that you're tripping, or a smoke detector in the conditioned space?

Comment: Can you trace the vent to the trunk line ?  They do make butterfly dampers but access sounds like it would be a problem a powered damper may be a better option these are sized by the duct size and can be found online , don’t put smoke or fire in your search as smoke or fire damper cost several orders of magnitude more. I usually put a damper close to the trunk if you have access I would check there prior to trying to add one.

Comment: Are there any combustion appliances  (eg gas or fuel oil))  in the machine room?

Comment: Unless the BBQ is built in, I'd suggest just moving it away from the air intake. Either make it a permanent move, or, if that's not acceptable, wheel it to the "cooking position" then back to the "storage position".

Comment: The smoke detector is in a conditioned space (Mechanical Room in the condo), which contains a gas-fired HW heater and an air handler using hot water (from the HW heater) for heating (https://firstco.com/documents/obsolete/TAQ-4-09.pdf); feeding into the air handler is a a MUA duct (the one in question) which also has a fan, so it is just a one-way vent.

The BBQ is not built in but uses a natural gas feed, it is located as far from the vent as possible, and cannot be moved off the patio (small garden and steps then parking area), and also the gas line is of limited length.

Comment: PS, the smoke detector is a 9V Ionization Smoke Alarm

Answer (score 1):

If the smoke is enough to trip the detector, but not enough to be objectionable to you, then you might consider replacing the smoke detector. A photoelectric type may be less prone to cooking-related nuisance alarms. A heat detector definitely will not trip for cooking smoke. A change to photoelectric is pretty easy. Check with your local authority to determine whether a heat detector would be acceptable for the location.

If the barbecue smoke comes from the fuel (ie wood or charcoal) I'd consider changing to a propane or natural gas fuel.

I don't love the idea of blocking the make-up air intake -- it would be all too easy for somebody to forget to unblock it after cooking, particularly if they don't understand the purpose of the intake. That said.. The grille covering the make up air intake may be steel. If it is then a magnetic sign could be an option for covering the intake. These are sometimes sold for covering heat registers inside the house as well. Ordinarily one would have to get within reach of the grille to place the cover, but if you secure it with rings or something at one end, then you could probably use a stick of some kind to lift it into place and to pull it back down again after cooking.

Comment: If the magnetic cover is an obnoxiously bright color, it's not likely to be forgotten _too_ often.

Comment: +1 for the magnetic cover, i was going to say that...

Comment: Note that if it's a *duct* smoke detector, it's likely to be photoelectric, and there's no such thing as a "duct heat detector", either